# How can I check if a passed entity supports the dollar operator?

Tags: r

lists and environments support the dollar operator in R, so I can do lst$whatever and env$whatever. Other entities, like atomic vectors, do not, for example I can't do vctr$whatever.

Is there a way to programmatically know if a passed entity supports the dollar operator?

having names() apparently is not good, because vectors can have names but are still not dollar indexable. ls() may seem a good approach but it requires that the entity can be converted to an environment, which may not always be the case.

Comment: `[[` works for lists, environments, and atomic vectors

Comment: @rawr so? I don't get the point

Comment: What is the actual scenario where you are receiving an object of unknown type but want to use `$` on it? Given that `$` requires you to hard code a name, it doesn't seem that flexible. It's mostly just a convenience functions for interactive R use. I'm having a hard time imaging when you might actually use this.

Comment: @MrFlick I want to perform a check if a passed entity supports the dollar operator, and if not, raise an error before the operator is actually applied. Many different entities may support dollar, of different types and classes. They can all be used for this function

Answer (score 2):

There's no method that will tell you for sure if something will respond to the `$` function. But even it there was, there's no guarantee what the `$` would do. The `$` is generic and classes are free to redefine how it behaves. For example, it could be used to draw a plot

```
foo <- function(x) {
  structure(x, class="foo")
}
`$.foo`<-function(x, v, ...) {
  plot(seq.int(nchar(v)), seq.int(nchar(v)), main=v)
}
x <- foo(5)
x$hello
```

[image: using $ to make a plot]

So just because it will respond to `$` doesn't mean it will actually return/extract a value.

If you expect `$` to have a certain behavior, then you should test for classes that actually have that behavior. If you want to just try to use `$`, you can always just catch the error in a `tryCatch`. Here we just return NULL when it fails but you could return whatever you like.

```
tryCatch(thing$whatever, error=function(e) NULL)
```